# Dynamically injecting a JDK dynamic proxy as spring bean - but only if no other implementation is available

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a situation where I want to look for interfaces annotated with a given annotation, then check if a matching implementation is available. If not, I want to make a bean available that is actually a JDK proxy of the interface, essentially exactly what:

```
@ConditionalOnMissingBean
```

would do, except without writing a factory method for each of those.

I have code that is working "sometimes" - it seems extremely sensitive to the classloader structure, specifically, wether classes are loaded from a springboot fat jar (works) or wether some part is loaded from a separate classpath entry (doesnt work, mostly).

here is what I am doing:

```
@Service
@Order(value = Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class RemotingImportService implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {

    private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(RemotingExportService.class);

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {


         // scan classpath with classgraph, then:
        for (ClassInfo classInfo : scanResult.getClassesWithAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class.getCanonicalName())) {

            Class c = Class.forName(classInfo.getName());

            if(beanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(c).length > 0) {
                implFound = true;
                log.info(c.getName()+" already has an implementation ... skipping");
                continue;
            }

            // create proxy, then:

            GenericBeanDefinition bdService = new GenericBeanDefinition();
            bdService.setBeanClassName(classInfo.getName());
            bdService.setInstanceSupplier(new ProxySupplier(proxy));
            bdService.setLazyInit(true);
            ((DefaultListableBeanFactory) beanFactory).registerBeanDefinition(classInfo.getName(), bdService);              
            log.info(c.getName()+" has NO implementation ... proxy registerd");

        }
```

in some cases, it seems that the beanfactory isn't finished, and

```
  beanFactory.getBeanNamesForType()
```

returns an empty list, although it does find beans for that type later. i am aware that messing with this is probably not ideal - but it would be nice to find a solution that plays nice with spring boot.

any suggestions on how to solve this? a way to mark a bean definition as "ConditionalOnMissingBean" would also be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `BeanPostProcessor` instead of `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`

`BeanPostProcessor` is operating by assembled beans, while `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` uses raw bean definitions. 
Read more [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-extension-bpp)

```
public class ConditionalOnMissingProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor, Ordered, ApplicationContextAware
{
private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(ConditionalOnMissingProcessor .class);

private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

// Ordering to last in chain.
@Override
public int getOrder()
{
    return Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE;
}

@Override
public void setApplicationContext(final ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException
{
    this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
}

/**
 * Process each bean and inject proxy objects in fields marked with: {@ConditionalOnMissingBean}
 */
@Override
public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(final Object bean, final String beanName) throws BeansException
{
    LOG.debug("Processing bean: " + beanName);
    final Class clazz = bean.getClass();
    ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(clazz, new ReflectionUtils.FieldCallback()
    {
        @Override
        public void doWith(final Field field)
        {
            try
            {
                if(field.isAnnotationPresent(ConditionalOnMissingBean.class))
                {
                    ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(field);
                     final String beanFieldName = field.getName();
                    ...
                    // Find proper implementation in application context
                    // Or create a proxy.
                    // Inject proxy or impl into a bean
                    field.set(bean, <value>));

                }
            }
            catch(IllegalAccessException e)
            {
                LOG.error("Cannot set " + field.getName() + " in " + beanName, e);
            }
        }
    });

    return bean;
}
```

UPD:

First of all, I have to say about disadvantages of your impl (IMHO):
- you are trying to scan classpath to find all interfaces with `@RemoteEndpoint` annotation, and, if current application context doesn't contain a bean that implemented this interface - create a proxy bean.
But what if I say, that not all interfaces marked with `@RemoteEndpoint` should be taken into account? Developer should explicitly mark those interfaces, and then you can create all needed beans (for example, developer makes a common-services library).
- probably you are specifying redudnant information, when marking impl class with `@RemotingEndpoint(value=RandomService.class)` annotation. You are already mentioned that when you **implemented** an interface.

There are multiple ways for implementing your idea

1. Using custom annotation on bean fields instead of `@Autowired`.

   pros:

   - simply check all bean fields for presence of your custom annotation, and inject dependency (proxy or impl), using `BeanPostProcessor`.

   cons:

   - developer should mark all bean dependencies with custom annotation;
   - it won't work if developer would have to obtain new dependencies at runtime.
2. Using regular `@Autowired` and `@Value` annotations for injecting remote service proxy
   In this case you should use `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` (as you already tried). You'll have to iterate over all bean definitions, collect a map of field names and interfaces of remote service proxies you'll have to register (dependencies meta info). And next step is creating and registering beans using dependencies meta info (creating new ones only if there is no implementation bean in context). Spring will autowire those fields later. But, those dependencies should be singleton beans.

   pros:

   - no mess with custom annotations;
   - works at runtime

   cons:

   - proxies are singletons (you need prototypes as diagram displayed).
3. Still using regular `@Autowired` and `@Value` annotations and `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`, but instead of registering new beans, you should register a `FactoryBean` for each interface `@RemoteEndpoint`.

   pros:

   - no mess with custom annotations.
   - works at runtime
   - prototype-scoped proxies

Comment: thank you very much. this way around is actually a lot nicer than what i was trying to do, since this also does away with any need for classapth scanning.

Comment: hmm ... i gave this a try. and it does see a lot of beans. however, i have a simple Service annotated class that has a couple of Autowired fields ... and i cannot see this class, because spring fails with an autowiring failure on that service before the post processor is even called. if i do Autowired(required=false) then it does in fact work like a charm, and i see the service with unset fields. any ideas? having to set that is ok, but it would be nicer without.

Comment: Autowired annotation has its own BeanPostProcessor. You should use your custom annotation RemoteEndpoint instead of Autowired to mark bean properties to be processed by your logic in RemotingImportService.

Comment: Also, your chek for applicationContext.getBeanNamesForType(s).length > 0 and further return could give a couple of problems. Someone may have same services in different beans, so getBeanNamesForType(s) will return 1 and your logic will stop producing new instanses of prototype bean.

Comment: hi. yes. well - the idea was to be able to say "give me the service, either local (regular autowired) or remote (inject the proxy of a remote object)", essentially without any knowledge of where this service actually runs. what i am now checking for is a.) is the field already wired or not, and b.) is the interface annotated correctly. - see here: https://github.com/rmalchow/remoting

Comment: awesome. thank you for taking the time. right now, with (required=true), Autowired already works. I also like the fact that I am now skipping the classpath scanning (didn't like that one either). i'll see how it goes with the third option though. thank you very much.